# Search for users having two different badges

Tags: support, badges

On a certain SE site, I'm interested in seeing how many people have both of two different badges (Promoter & Tumbleweed).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/812736) will return the users who has the Promoter, Tumbleweed badges on a specific site.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 UserId AS [User Link]
FROM Badges
WHERE Name IN ('Promoter', 'Tumbleweed')
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Name) = 2
```

Note: Adding `TOP 1000` to avoid the timeout issue,